# GetAssetPreview always returns null for UnityEngine.UI.Image

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I have an array of prefabs i want to show a preview of in my custom editor. This works for gameobjects with a mesh renderer, for example the basic quad. However when i try to use `AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview(tilePrefab.gameObject);` on gameobject with a UnityEngine.UI.Image and a canvas renderer it always returns null.

Below is the part of the code that draws the previews.

```
public class MapEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        for (int prefabIndex = 0; prefabIndex < TileSet.TilePrefabs.Count; prefabIndex++)
            DrawIconTexture(prefabIndex, columnCount);
    }

    private void DrawIconTexture(int prefabIndex, int columnCount)
    {
        TileBehaviour tilePrefab = TileSet.TilePrefabs[prefabIndex];
        Texture iconTexture = AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview(tilePrefab.gameObject);
        Rect iconRect = GetIconRect(prefabIndex, columnCount);

        if (iconTexture != null)
            GUI.DrawTexture(iconRect, iconTexture);
        else if (AssetPreview.IsLoadingAssetPreview(tilePrefab.gameObject.GetInstanceID()))
            Repaint();
    }
}
```

I know GetAssetPreview loads assets async, that is solved by the repaint. I have also tried

```
while(iconTexture == null)
    iconTexture = AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview(tilePrefab.gameObject);
```

But that never finishes.

I also tried to use the texture of the Image

```
if (iconTexture == null)
    iconTexture = tilePrefab.GetComponent<Image>().sprite.texture;
```

But that does not work because the sprite is in an atlas and all of the atlas is shown.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** misread the question. I actually tried to use IsLoadingAssetPreview and IsLoadingAssetPreviews for few hours, without success. I ended up using a sad little trick

```
if (_previews.All(pair => pair.Value != null)) return;
_previews = GeneratePreviews();
```

I put that in the `Update()` loop of my EditorWindow. It's pretty hacky, I'm going to ask Unity if the AssetPreview methods are actually working.

**Old answer, irrelevant:**

You are not using the while loop and GetAssetPreview correctly.

GetAssetPreview will launch an asynchronous loading of the preview. To know if the preview is fully loaded you need to call [AssetPreview.IsLoadingAssetPreview](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPreview.IsLoadingAssetPreview.html).

A pretty simple and brutal way of doing it (it will block execution) is :

```
var preview = AssetPreview.GetAssetPreview(item);
while (AssetPreview.IsLoadingAssetPreview(item.GetInstanceID())) {
     // Loading
}
```

As usual, careful with while loops. Note that there is also a [AssetPreview.IsLoadingAssetPreviews](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetPreview.IsLoadingAssetPreviews.html) method with no parameters.

Comment: If you check my question that is how i use it (the else if). The only difference being that i dont use a while, i use repaint which cause the function to be called the next frame.

Comment: Ha sorry, missed that ...
I just fought with the AssetPreview.IsloadingAssetPreviews() for 4 hours, without success. I ended up storing a reference to the previews in an array, and checking on each Update() of my EditorWindow `if(previewsArray.Any(t => t == null) { GetPreviews() }`. 

As the Previews are cached, that does the trick without too much overhead ...

Answer (score -2):

you should just use "using UnityEditor"